# JQuery not working , show element by id does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an element that is hidden but on the action, it must appear.

**code:**

```
<a href="#Comment" class="btn btn-control" id="Commentbtn"> 
<svg class="olymp-comments-post-icon"><use xlink:href="../svg-icons/sprites/icons.svg#olymp-comments-post-icon"></use></svg>
</a>    

<form class="need-validation d-none" id="commentbox">
   .
   .
   .
</form>

 <script>
$("#Commentbtn").click(function () {
$("commentbox").removeClass("need-validation d-none");
 $("commentbox").addClass("need-validation d-block");
});
</script>
```

I expect when the element to be shown after clicking the  tag
but it does not
Even the classes not changed

Comment: please share your markup as well

Comment: You have an type error in `$("commentbox")` should be  `$("#commentbox")`

Comment: i expect that when i click on the <a> tag the element would be showen but it does not even the classes not changed.

Comment: @OmarOdeh tips: https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `#` for id selector

For more information - [jQuery Selectors](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-selectors.htm)

```
$("#Commentbtn").click(function () {
                    $("#commentbox").removeClass("need-validation d-none");
                    $("#commentbox").addClass("need-validation d-block");
                });
```

Comment: Should a question like this not be closed as `a simple typographical `

Comment: yeah it could be, but as this is new contributor and may not understand just comment but it would be helpful to show some corrected code